# Systematic way to debug Minified React error #321

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a component to be used across a lot of lists.

Here's the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-williamson-nhuus?file=/src/App.js)

Basically I have a lot of lists, and on top of each list I want to have a toolbar of actions. I call it `ListActions`. Each `ListActions` can contain multiple `ListAction` button in it.

And I want my component to be flexible, so that developers can provide sinle action JSX, multiple actions JXS or a react component that returns single or multiple actions.

It works great on development. But when I build it, without getting any warnings related to hooks I see this error:

> Uncaught Error: Minified React error #130; visit [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=object&args%5B%5D=) for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

And when I follow the links ([here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321) and [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)) I see that there are a couple of rules related to the hooks. But I don't find any breaching of those rules in my code.

How can I fix this?